# download JSON in background and put data into CoreData fetch into TableView in Swift

Tags: json, core-data, swift2

here is the problem, I am downloading data from (JSON) via SwiftyJson, and I am doing it in application launch means every launch I am sending request to server, and then I save it into coreData and want to fetch it into array of struct and populate it into tableView, this is what I want to do generally, and I want to load data from CoreData when I can't conncet to the server because of connection or anything else,

Here is what I have done so far

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool { 

json()

}

func json {
deleteData()

// doing the parse and serialization
saveJson()

}

savejson{

// save into coredata ... manageContext and ....
}
// and rest of appdelegate


}
deleteData{

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: ",myentityName")
            fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        do {

            let results = try manageContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
            for manageObject in results{

                let managedObjectData : NSManagedObject = manageObject as! NSManagedObject

                manageContext.deleteObject(managedObjectData)
            }
        }catch let error as NSError {

            print(" error : \(error) \(error.userInfo) ")
        }

    }


}
```

and then I am using the data in another viewController (tableViewController)

```
Class table: UITableViewController{

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

fetchCoreDate()  //and put it into struct

}

//rest of the class table for table populate

}
```

and here is the struct I am use to pass the data between viewController

```
  struct logs{

var logId: String
var logName: String
}
```

The problem is I am download all the data as I print them in console, I am seeing the data in table but when I put the delete function there, it will delete eveything , I am trying to delete the past data and replace them with new ones but Json download is longer time than application launch so it finish downloading after the table is loaded and then the table is not load the new data coming and I should omit the delete function to see the data but It always add to the past data and I see duplications of records (if omit the delete)

**with delete function I see nothing in table without it I will see duplicate of that,** (keep in mind that I want download the data and replace them with new ones since it will add sometimes and sometimes not)

sorry its a bit long but the scenario is somehow about working between different viewController, so I should  have post them all

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer some days of struggling with it, the answer lies within the palce you put for delete method it should be reight before task.resue() or prior to async task

```
func json {

....
....
deletedata
asynctask(...)

// doing the parse and serialization
saveJson()

}
```

OR

```
func json {

{
// doing the parse and serialization
saveJson()
deleteData()}
task.resume()


}
```